# wordpress: on send email save fields to database - error 500

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to save the contents of a submission form to a database table. But when I submit the form I receive error 500 without any debug error displaying. If I remove the line which inserts data to the table then the form is being sent without any errors.

Here is the code:

```
function send_mail($fields)
{
    $subject = "New Quotation Form";
    $to = ["to@email.com"];

    extract($fields);
    ob_start();
    require 'email-template.php';
    $message = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    //insert quotation form contents to database table submitted_forms
    global $wbpd;
    $table = "submitted_forms";
    $data = array(
            'content' => $message,
            'datetime' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            'from_email' => $email
        );

    $ok = $wpdb->insert($table, $data); //it breaks here, if I remove it form is sent successfully

    if($wpdb->last_error !== '') :

        $str   = htmlspecialchars( $wpdb->last_error, ENT_QUOTES );
        $query = htmlspecialchars( $wpdb->last_query, ENT_QUOTES );

        print "<div id='error'>
        <p class='wpdberror'><strong>WordPress database error:</strong> [$str]<br />
        <code>$query</code></p>
        </div>";

    endif;

    $replyTo =   "Reply-To: ".$email;
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        $replyTo
    );

    file_put_contents("mail.html", $message);

    $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    return $sent;
}
```

Comment: Check your error logs because 500 error usually writes more information to the log, or turn on error reporting

Comment: Does the table `submitted_forms` already exist with the correct column names etc? Can we see the code which creates that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo :

```
global $wbpd; //global $wpdb;
```